# p-calendar primeng unable to use ngmodel and pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, primeng

I am trying to use p-calendar from ng-prime with ngmodel to bind a date from the server

```
 <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
             [locale]="es"
             [hidden]="!editing"
             dateFormat="d/mm/yy"
             appendTo="body"
             class="pos-cal mar-left-txt"
             [(ngModel)]="currentUserData.person.dateOfBirth">
 </p-calendar>

 <p [hidden]="editing">
     {{currentUserData.person.dateOfBirth | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
 </p>
```

this code does what i want i just have one problem. selected date i have set as today but its not what i wish to use to display. i want to display the date of birth on p-calendar

when i select a date from the calendar it binds to the paragraph
usually i would just use a pipe but it hasnt worked

Comment: why you have use ngMode two time you can use selectedDate only

Comment: i use it the second time to bind it to the paragraph. it wasnt binding without it

Comment: can you check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-6-calendar

Comment: i know how to get the date to show in that case. my problem is i wish for the date from my server to be displayed not the selecteddate which is just a stopper till i find a permanent solution. i wish to display the users birthday as the default date in p-calendar and in the paragraph. i dont wish to display or even use selected date anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The only case I have found is when you don't inilized `selectedDate`,try to set `selectedDate` to `currentUserData.person.dateOfBirth`

in my example Ijust set to current date

*template*

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
             [hidden]="!editing"
             dateFormat="d/mm/yy"
             appendTo="body" (onBlur)="editing = !editing"  >
 </p-calendar>

 <p [hidden]="editing" (click)="editing = !editing">
     {{selectedDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
 </p>
```

*component*

```
  selectedDate;
  editing = false
  constructor() {
    this.selectedDate = new Date();
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-6-calendar)

Comment: i dont wish for it to be selected date though. i wish for the date i retrieve from the server to be the date shown. Selecteddate is merely a stopper till i find a solution to currentUserData.person.dateOfBirth not displaying